Automorphism of a character and Frobenius morphism
Let $T$ be a torus, and let $X(T)$ be its characters group (the group of homomorphisms $T \to \mathbb{G}_m$).
I am trying to understand the proof of the following result (Proposition 4.2.3) in Digne-Michel's book.

Let $F$ be a Frobenius endomorphism attached to an $\mathbb{F}_q$ structure on $T$. Then there exists $\tau \in \operatorname{GL}(X(T))$ such that $F=q\tau$.

The proof says briefly that we define $\tau$ by the left commutative square, and that we can extend it with a right commutative square as follows:

where $A$ and $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_q[x,x^{-1}]$ are the algebras of $T$ and $\mathbb{G}_m$ respectively, and $\Phi$ and $\Phi_0$ are the corresponding arithmetic Frobenius endomorphisms, and $\alpha\in X(T)$ and $\alpha^*$ is the corresponding algebras morphism. The claim in the proof is that

The left square is by invertibility of the arithmetic Frobenius as a semilinear morphism of algebras.
The right-most vertical morphism is $\tau(\alpha)^*$ since $ F^*\circ \Phi$ and $ F\circ \Phi_0$ are the algebra morphisms $a\mapsto a^q $
The commutativity of the rightmost square gives $F=q\tau$.

My question is

how do we get 1, 2 and 3?
I am mostly interested in knowing the meaning of $q\tau$ in 3.

I believe that the $F$ in 3. is  not the Frobenius $F:T\to T$, but rather a Frobenius $F:X(T)\to X(T)$ induced by the one on $T$. But what is this multiplication by $q$?
Thank you.
